# Sort by Time using SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using VB and MySQL. I have a field named xTime and the data type is TIME. I am trying to find a way to order it ASC or enable it to have the PM/AM in it. Right now my Data is as follows and I need the 3:20 and 5:50 to be after since those should be pm. Any ideas?

```
62      4       3       03:20:00
61      4       3       05:50:00
56      1       1       07:40:00
```

Here is my SQL Statement:

```
    SELECT        ReserveID, MembershipID, Player_Count, `Time`, CourseID, `Date`  
    FROM            reserve  
    WHERE        (CourseID = 1) AND (`Date` = CURDATE())  
    ORDER BY `Time`
```

Comment: you should be able to order by time.  Please post your query, it may help in finding why it is not sorting correctly.

Comment: Okay I have added the Query. I know it is in asc ordering but trying to figure out how to format either time or datatype again so its not military time either.

Comment: How can you possibly tell that `03:20:00` is after `07:40:00`?  What is the break point?  Actually, `03:20:00` is always early morning, and in a single time zone, always precedes `07:40:00` on the same day.  `15:20:00` is the afternoon time.  You have to deal with conversion/reformatting of values somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code and your data seem to be fine. Your code is ordering by time ascendingly and your results are displaying it the way they should. The issue is that you're interpreting the data in the wrong way:

> I need the 3:20 and 5:50 to be after since those should be pm

`3:20` and `5:50` must be before `7:40` always, because those are all `AM` times. `3:20 PM` is equal to `15:20` and `5:50 PM` is equal to `17:40`.

Comment: Is there a way to insert AM PM fields into the database? or how should I change the data because I don't want to use military time to display them.

Comment: Then [format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) them when you display them